# iOS drag and drop from table view cell to image view

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, drag-and-drop

I need help implementing a drag and drop gesture, I would like to know Your opinion to find the best approach.

I have a view controller with a uitableview on the right and some image views on the left.

I would like to allow the user to drag every cell of the table view on one of the image views. Basically the drag-n-drop will fail if the cell is not released on one of the image views, otherwise the image view will change image according to the dropped cell.

What do You think is the best way to achieve this?

In addition, when the user start dragging, I would like that he drags around a particular shaped subview, with image and data, not drag the semitransparent cell.

Thanks a lot, Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` on every `UITableViewCell`, when you recognize a long tap, the drag begins, you could add a layer on the tableviewcell to indicate that this is the cell that is being dragged,
Now instead of dragging around the cell itself, you would drag a UIImageView that contains your particular shaped image, you will need to use, `touchesBegan, touchesMoved and touchesEnded` to move the image around, when touches ended you will need to test if the UIImageView is inside the UIImageView that you want to drop it on

This is the general concept, you will have to work on it a little

Comment: I think it's a good approach. I will try to implement, thanks! ;)